# Passar dados entre fragmentos e Activitys com radio button

Tags: android

Estou com problemas para passar dados de uma activity para um fragment, gostaria de usar um radio button para definir um parametro para uma variavel, dps passar esse valor para o fragment poder fazer o tratamento, exemplo... 
Na hora de logar o usuario escolheria a opcao adm e esse parametro seria enviado ao fragment que là dentro de um if para determinar a opçao escolhida. Como passar esses dados ???

A estrutura seria mais ou menos assim...

### Verificando o tipo na activity

```
if (morador.isChecked()){
                tipo = "morador";
            }
            if (sindico.isChecked()){
                tipo = "sindico";
            }
```

### No fragment

Aqui eu teria que receber essa variavel tipo lá da activity com os valores e passar a tratar os dados...

```
    //Caminho

    if(tipo == sindico) {

        databaseReference1 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado).child("nome");
        databaseReference2 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado).child("apartamento");
        databaseReference3 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado).child("bloco");

   }else if(tipo == morador) {
         databaseReference1 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Sindico").child(usuarioLogado).child("nome");
        databaseReference2 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Sindico").child(usuarioLogado).child("apartamento");
        databaseReference3 = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Sindico").child(usuarioLogado).child("bloco");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de Chamar sua Fragment coloca isso:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("VarTpUsuario", VarTpUsuario);
frag.setArguments(args);
```

Na Fragment, tenta isso:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
VarTpUsuario = myIntent.getString("VarTpUsuario");
```